# dynatree как сделать выбранными узлы только одного дерева

Tags: jquery

Есть такая структура:

```
--1
   -a
   -b
--2
   -c
   -d
     -e
   -f
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе(select) узла 1-го дерева снять выделение с узлов 2-го дерева?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в инициализации плагина для элемента добавить обработчик `onSelect`:

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
    […]
    onSelect: function(flag, node) {
        // это пример из документации, но по аналогии вы можете сделать свои условия
        if( ! flag )
            alert("You deselected node with title " + node.data.title);
        var selectedNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes();
        var selectedKeys = $.map(selectedNodes, function(node){
            return node.data.key;
        });
        alert("Selected keys: " + selectedKeys.join(", "));
    },
    […]
});
```

Comment: Roman, спасибо за ответ. Обработчик я конечно же добавил. Пример этот смотрел. Не получается при селекте например^^ узла "е" снять выделение со всех узлов 1 дерева.

Comment: Можете на JSFiddle сделать рабочий пример вашего кода?

Answer (score 0):

Все получилось. В обработчике onSelect использовал node.getKeyPath() для нахождения ключа верхнего родителя. И проверяем при выборе узла изменился родитель или нет, если да снимаем выделение.